# How to determine/set the Java classpath for an Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, java

l am trying to make use of some proprietary Oracle Java classes/methods using an Oracle provided virtual machine (E-Business Suite Vision, Oracle 12.2.28)

On my test server I define a function:

```
[oracle@apps java_test]$ sqlplus USER/PASS@SID

SQL*Plus: Release 10.1.0.5.0 - Production on Tue May 21 10:21:24 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> create or replace function methodname(foo in varchar2, bar in varchar2)
return varchar2 as
language java
name 'path.to.classname.methodname(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
/  2    3    4    5  

Function created.
```

Which seems to compile. However when I attempt to call it, I get the following error.

```
SQL> select methodname('foo', 'bar') FROM DUAL;
select methodname('foo', 'bar') FROM DUAL
                                                                                                                                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29540: class path/to/classname does not exist
```

l know for a fact that this class exists at `/u01/install/APPS/fs1/EBSapps/comn/java/classes/path/to/classname.class`. The question is have is, how do I set the classpath for the database (either permanently or for the session) so that it can access this method? Alternatively, is there a query to determine what the classpath is so that I can copy the classes to the proper location in the operating system?

Comment: The loadJava tool is what you're after. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdev/loadjava-tool.html#GUID-033299E6-07E2-4C2C-9E26-A2FE25118F1C

Answer (score 3):

The JVM embedded in your Oracle database only allows you to access java classes **loaded inside** that database: accessing external classes (from OS files) is not allowed.

First you need to find out what java classes are already loaded in your database by reading dictionary view `ALL_JAVA_CLASSES`. You will find that it has already 10's of thousands of classes loaded.

```
SQL> select owner, count(*) from all_java_classes group by owner order by owner;

OWNER        COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
MDSYS            1134
ORDSYS           1944
SYS             34358

3 rows selected.
```

But it is unlikely that the EBS-specific classes you want to invoke are there. So you then need to load those classes in your database.

You can do that using the `loadjava` command line tool, which lets you load entire jar files into your database. Or you can also use the `DBMS_JAVA` package, specifically the `LOADJAVA()` method.

Of course those EBS classes may have dependencies on other EBS or third-party classes. You will then also need to load those.

Read about it in the Java Developer's Guide (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdev)